# QObject::connect not starting Tcp signal

Tags: c++, qt, tcp

**Haveing issues getting my  QObject to connect to the tcp start..
Any suggestions please and thankyou for your time**

seems the start never gets called...

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{
      LoginServer tcpServer;
      QObject::connect(&tcpServer, SIGNAL(tcpServer::stopped()), this, SLOT(tcpServer::start(port)));
}
```

**loginserver.h**

```
signals:
    void stopped();
public slots:
    void start(quint16 port);
    void stop();
private slots:
    void threadStarted();
    void threadFinished();
protected:
    void incomingConnection(qintptr) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
private:
    QAtomicInt activeSessions;
    QSemaphore threadWaitSemaphore;
```

**Loginserver.cpp**

```
void LoginServer::start(quint16 port)
{
    // Start the Login server
    // QHostAddress::Any
    //QHostAddress::LocalHost
    if (!listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))
    {
        QString Login_Server_Error = QStringLiteral("Couldn't start the login server");
        ui->textBrowser->append(Login_Server_Error);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        QString Login_Server_Connection = QStringLiteral("Login Server Started on port: %1").arg(port);
        ui->textBrowser->append(Login_Server_Connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `stopped` signal being emitted?

Comment: Your `QObject::connect()` call looks fishy. Try using the [new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) and see if that resolves your problem (or gives you an error message.)

Comment: You cannot connect a signal with zero arguments to a slot with one argument. Please check your runtime error messages.

Comment: the signal stopped is emitted from the moc' file

// SIGNAL 0
void LoginServer::stopped()
{
    QMetaObject::activate(this, &staticMetaObject, 0, Q_NULLPTR);
}

Comment: This tells us nothing. You still are ignoring the console output from your application. Have a look there.